# How to use single facebook app to login to multiple domains

Tags: php, facebook

I have four websites. I have implemented facebook login in a website. it works fine. but I can't use the same app id and secret to other domains.

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

when I add domains to app Domains it throws the following error

> App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: anothersite.com

I use hybridauth in yii framework 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one domain for one platform. There is a workaround, you can use the "website" platform with one domain and the "canvas" platform for another one, for example. I am not sure if that it allowed though.